# What signal does the JVM raise during an unhandled exception?

Tags: java, unix, signals

What signal (`SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, ...) does the JVM raise during an unhandled exception?

For example, the exception might be `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Which JVM implementation are you curious about?

Comment: Why would the JVM raise a POSIX signal at all?

Comment: @EricM, @chrylis, @SotiriosDelimanolis, I'm asking the question because I wrote a bash script that executes a java program.  I created a simple bash [library](https://github.com/ATNI/keyway/blob/master/keyway_lib.sh) to manage lock files.  The library traps `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` to ensure the lock file is deleted even if the process is `CTRL-C`'d or `kill`'d.  The program raised a `NumberFormatException` and the lock file was not removed.  I'm using: `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.0pre) (rhel-1.66.1.13.0.el6-x86_64)`.

Comment: Right... because the JVM doesn't use external OS signals for internal exceptions.

Comment: Well, I'd agree with you but normal termination of the JVM deletes the lock file at the end of the script.  When an exception was raised, the lock file was not removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unhandled exceptions don't necessarily cause the JVM to raise a signal - it isn't necessary: the exception is caught by the Java system code and handled there (prints a stack trace and exits for instance).

There may be cases in which JVMs raise a signal in order to invoke a signal handler to log further diagnostic information.

On the other hand, the Oracle JVM (for instance) does install signal handlers to catch some specific errors and convert them to exceptions - see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html) for more details.

EDIT to followup on the comments above, and based on the link to the source (though you don't show the script that calls the failing Java program AFAICT):

The traps you've installed cause the shell interpreter to install signal handlers in case it receives SIGINT/...  They don't get invoked if a child process receives such a signal (a raise causes the process in question to receive the signal - to signal another process you need to use kill and friends).

So even if the JVM were to raise a signal, the shell would not get it.

What could be happening in your case is that bash is configured to exit on error (e.g. set -o errexit), and so the lock release code does not get executed simply because the JVM's exit code is non null due to the unhandled exception.

To fix this, add ERR (and maybe EXIT) to the signal_spec of your trap call.

Comment: Just wanted to update this (finally). I did need to trap ERR -- though I stopped trying to clean up afterwards.  Instead I'm logging the issue.  Thanks again for your help!